# Is it a good practice? Create smaller questions to answer an original question by another user

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, needs-more-focus

I come across a set of questions like these:

[What are the differences between Network and HTTP(s) load balancer in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535226/difference-between-network-and-https-load-balancer-in-gcp/41535227)

[How do I configure managed instance group and autoscaling in Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541761/setting-up-managed-instance-group-and-autoscaling-in-google-cloud-platform/41541762#41541762)

which are actually part of an attempt to answer part of the original question here: [Use existent VM Instace (bitnami) for Autoscale Group of Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467192/use-existent-vm-instace-bitnami-for-autoscale-group-of-instances/41541921#41541921)

It seems to me this approach helps the OP to break down the original question into smaller parts and make it easier to answer and respond.

On the downside I can see it can lead to a lot of small Q&A that might be devoid of context.

Do you think it is a good idea?

Comment: I mean, that likely makes it much easier to dupe close at least.

Comment: Not my area of expertise – so I'm hesitant to cast a close vote – but it seems to me that the root cause of all of this is that the original question is (far) too broad. Either that, or this fella answered a simple question with far too much info :-)

Comment: Looks a bit like a nasty try of getting more votes by splitting the answer into different post. He may had some effort to get all the information, but it shouldn't be desired to do these "tricks".

Comment: I think giving back to the community is everything in stackoverflow. I was the one who wrote the above answers in a Q&A style. I have checked for the duplicates, if there had been any, I would have tagged it. Not everyone follows by your so called "trick" @tom. More over the question is not a brief one. You can't write the whole answer at a single time, if so it would take pages to do that. I feel dejected for the down votes after putting so much efforts in writing the answer. So, precisely stackoverflow is not giving back to community. It is full of competitions and egos. Sad.

Comment: I feel each question answers their part. I do not feel it is out of context. Moreover, as @Tom said, If I wanted to get more upvotes, I should not have written the answer at the first place. As, the user who asked that question has only 1 reputation who cannot upvote any answer.

Comment: Is it only me who gets the impression that those three questions may not fit SO? SU or SF maybe?

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar That OP isn't the only user in this site and certainly not the only person who might think about voting.

Comment: Are the questions/answers: 1. On-topic? 2. Well written/understandable/answerable on their own? In this case it seems like a resounding *yes* on both fronts. Eureka, knowledge has been disseminated. I don't think anyone needs to look further than that.

Comment: Thank you @deceze for the wonderful feedback. As some of the above questions has been put on hold, I will try to edit the questions to look more searchable and understandable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is it a good practice? Create smaller questions to answer an original question by another user

Of course it's a good practice: you are breaking down a "too broad" question, with it's subsets that can arguably reused on other purposes. Do note, each of these questions should be able to stand on their own: they are within the bounds of what SO considers a good question.

> It seems to me this approach helps the OP to break down the original question into smaller parts and make it easier to answer and respond.

Good for him! He's using the site how it meant to be used: asking specific questions that allow competing answers. So, rather than "How do I go about designing an exact bow and arrow with the dart board and quiver like the one below using CSS only?", he asks "How to give the sensation of profundity to a circumference?", "How can I make complex shape, like a bow?", "How to allow a element to be dragged?", etc. As Tim post said:

> there seems to be quite a bit of useful stuff there, *it's just unfortunately compiled in a way that doesn't work well for Stack Overflow*.

So, make sure that the content you submit is compiled in a way that works with SO.

Comment: I agree it is a good approach. I discovered this set of Q&A at the 'subquestion' level and then realised there is a parent question. Lakshman has put in a lot of effort in the answers.  Wish there is a easier way to go back to the OP question. Maybe I should update the question to add 'how can we refine and make approach better'

Comment: Thanks braiam and @AnthonyKong for appreciating the efforts. But seeing the downvotes to the questions and answer I wrote, kinda feels the efforts has gone waste.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar It seems to me most feedbacks here are rather positive. On the other hand, downvotes on SO... might be for other reasons? Wish they added comments to explain...

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar One thing that does not look right, at least with the first question, is that it does not look like a question at all. This site adheres to particular format, and statements like "This question is a part of another question's answer" make it feel somewhat out of place, especially when there is no question, even pro-forma, asked at all in that particular piece.

Comment: I agree totally, good approach in my eyes to differentiate the tasks. @LakshmanDiwaakar gave you some up votes to counter the downs.

Comment: I love the approach, and have upvoted @LakshmanDiwaakar's answers. However, I do think that the questions themselves could be better formatted. I think it would be helpful to phrase them as questions, and to include at least some of the original context. I suspect this would aid other users who are trying to answer a similar question, since they might arrive at it from a similar context.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar What artem said. Even though SO policy encourages self-answered questions I've noticed that such questions usually attract downvotes if they haven't been written in the form of a question. So please go back and modify those questions to make them look like the kind of good question that SO regulars will want to answer.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar I think your answer is fine. However, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541761/setting-up-managed-instance-group-and-autoscaling-in-google-cloud-platform) "question" isn't a question at all. If I were to see this question just browsing SO, I'd probably downvote due to it not actually being a question. I think that's the only issue here, and I am fairly sure it's why you got downvotes.

Comment: @GrahamHarper Thank you for accepting the approach. As per your suggestion, I have edited the question. @ Christopher, PM 2Ring As some of my questions are put on hold, I will edit the questions to look more understandable and resubmit for opening the question. Thanks for all the support.

Comment: This answer ignores the glaring problems in the execution. The questions as written *don't* seem to stand very well on their own.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm answering the general case... where did you get the idea that I was doing something else?

Comment: @Braiam Answering the "general case" while ignoring how it applies to the specific example presented amounts to bad advice. Where did you get the idea that implicitly praising low quality work is a good thing?

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, the question isn't tagged "specific question". He wants to know if "in general" it's an accepted practice, to which the answer is a rotund YES

Comment: Dear Lord, man. Providing general analysis by no means excludes explaining that the general analysis is inapplicable because of other specific circumstances. Thanks for discouraging people from closing or editing these questions to get them up to snuff and actively making SO a little bit worse place.

Comment: @jpmc26 I reject the notion that you can not use my counsel as guidance. If you want to dwell on the specific case, be my guess, but do it in **your own answer**. As is it, this answer is a sensible approach to this kind of issues, and I intend to keep it like that. Unless the asker is asking about a particular case, general answers are preferred.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar One of your questions is now much better, thanks for fixing it. But [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541761/setting-up-managed-instance-group-and-autoscaling-in-google-cloud-platform) still needs work to make it into a proper question that can be judged on its own merits, as described in [IMSoP's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341407/4014959).

Comment: @Pm2 Ring. Thank you for the feedback. I will change the question more understandable as soon an possible.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar Your question is _understandable_, apart from the fact that  it relies on the reader referencing the other questions to get the full picture. The main problem is that it still doesn't fit the model of what a good SO question is supposed to looks like, it looks more like the introduction of a blog post. But SO isn't a blog.

Answer (score 8):

The idea of breaking down a broad question into sub-questions seems like a good one - it's basically what the "too broad" policy is *instructing* you to do. But these new questions should be *instead of* the original, not subservient to it. And the fact they were created this way is a historical footnote, not an on-going part of their existence.

If the original question is too broad, it may at some point be closed, and even deleted. It's therefore imperative that the new questions don't rely on it, and probably they shouldn't even reference it. They might reference *each other*, or maybe the answer to one might reference another, but if you end up writing "this is part 1 of a series of 10, click here to see the index", you're no longer writing a Q&A, you're writing a blog  or tutorial. And that doesn't belong here.

What's more, each of these new questions will stand and fall on its own merits; they should each be high quality and on-topic. If you split a question into a part that discusses software design, and a part that covers hardware configuration, the hardware part will probably be flagged as "Off-topic, migrate to Super User or Server Fault?" So even linking between the questions should be incidental, not essential to understanding each.